# Duplication among Dockerfiles

Tags: docker, duplicates, dockerfile

I am installing OpenStack Keystone now.
For standalone Keystone needs three components: mysql, python, and apache2.

Absolutely I can’t pick all of them to the base, I made python as a base image, and others were inserted as RUN statements for installing mysql and apache2.

I think that the RUN statements are duplication because all the three components exist on Docker Public Registry.

Is there any good solution or proper way to reuse the existing external Dockerfile???

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some confusion here about what a Dockerfile does: it defines a single Docker image. In general, the recommended way to run applications in Docker is to have a container for each service and have them connect to other services in other containers as needed (more on this later).

In your case, it sounds like your application consists of OpenStack Keystone (which requires Python and Apache to run) and MySQL. So I would install Python & Apache in your Dockerfile, and set up MySQL (possibly just using the image from the public repository) as a separate container that the OpenStack container connects to over the network.

As mentioned above, this scenario is the recommended way to run Docker applications - it follows the Unix paradigm of "each app does only one thing, but does it very well". Each container does one thing only and connects to any other services in other containers. But it is possible to run multiple services in the same container - eg. Keystone running on Apache/python AND MySQL in the same container. If this is your goal, you would write a Dockerfile that installs everything and gets everything running together. This Dockerfile is likely to be pretty complicated and will require an ENTRYPOINT that gets both MySQL and Apache working together. You're likely to wind up duplicating a lot of the work that has already gone into the standard MySQL and Apache images.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of `Docker Compose` to run you application having  `mysql, python, and apache2.`

Using Docker compose will allow you to control the application setup using a single command. You just need to write a `DockerCompose.yml` file and also Dockerfiles corresponding to containers you will setup.

In your case you can have a dockerfile for setting up a python and apache2 container and other Dockerfile having mysql as the base image for setting up the said container.